# an error when add blank data on top drop downlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a dropdown, I have a datasource and i wanted to add blank data it worked but the value that selected always 0

My code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
listhostel()   
End Sub

Protected Sub listhostel()
Dim dash As New DataSet
Dim clas As New Class1

dash = clas.returndataset("select ID as idhostel,Nama from Hostel")

listhotelx.DataSource = dash
listhotelx.DataBind()
listhotelx.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Select --", 0))
End Sub

Protected Sub viewdatagrid_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles viewdatagrid.Click    
Label1.Text = listhotelx.SelectedValue 
viewdata()
End Sub
```

The file.aspx

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="listhotelx" runat="server" DataTextField="Nama"
 DataValueField="idhostel" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: want to add in code behind or in markup ( aspx ) ?

Comment: What value other than 0 do you want it to be?

Answer (score 0):

Call the DropDownList.DataBind() method after adding the new item to dropdownlist.
The ListItem method accept only string values, so in your code replace 0 with "0"

```
Protected Sub listhostel()
Dim dash As New DataSet
Dim clas As New Class1

dash = clas.returndataset("select ID as idhostel,Nama from Hostel")

listhotelx.DataSource = dash    
listhotelx.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("-- Select --", "0")) // here the 2nd argument is string.
listhotelx.DataBind()
End Sub

//    I have checked this code and it works fine for me
```

I have also add an item to my dropdownlist

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
   <asp:ListItem Text="name1" Value="-1" ></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And on the button click when I add a new item, It successfully adds the item at index 0.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("name", "-1"));         
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: um, the databind() is already in the question: `listhotelx.DataBind()`. Plus this answer you should add the item *after* the binding unless the data source already contained an item called `-- Select --`

Answer (score 0):

After you databind and add the item, notice how you can also set the items SelectedIndex:

```
listhotelx.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("-- Select --", String.Empty));
listhotelx.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error you getting because `ListItem` must have `(string,string)` as an argument and you are passing `("-- Select --",0)` which is `(string,int)`.

If you want to add blank data on top then you just need to enter empty string.

```
listhotelx.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
listhotelx.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @JeremyThompson  `ListItem(Text, Value)` so it will show `-- Select --` as your answer but he want `Blank`.

Comment: I thought he could get a blank item to work and wanted to change selected index `i wanted to add blank data it worked but the value that selected always 0` - meh nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

on Page_Load must add Page.IsPostBack

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            listhostel()
        End If
    End Sub
```